# Random screen blinking/switching inputs

Tags: display, troubleshooting, dvi

My monitor has been been randomly trying to switch inputs automatically, causing a black screen for several seconds.
I think it is switching inputs because it displays the associated [DVI] OSD block.
It only does this when running certain programs that aren't even heavy loads 
such as Isaac:AB+ occasionally , PCSX2 (PS2 Emulator) every few seconds/minutes , and sometimes Chrome (but only in fullscreen).

The monitor is a ViewSonic VX2240w-2, using DVI-D input. PC outputs DVI-D through NVidia GForce GTX 1050 Ti graphics card.
When it tries to switch it goes from DVI back to DVI as there is no other input signal.

Any ideas as to why it would be doing this or how to fix it?

Comment: I was about to ask a question about a blinking issue that I am facing, until I read your question. I have two monitors connected, but using only one at a time, so I'm thinking maybe my PC is trying to switch inputs as well. I'll remove one of them and keep an eye to see if it happens again. Please post any useful information you might have from your end. Thanks!